# Rust expected dyn ToString, found f64

Tags: rust, traits

I am struggling with code to write containers to file. I have specified a trait bound of `std::fmt::Display` because any type implementing this has `to_string()`. `f64` implements this trait, so I don't understand how this error could happen. I checked the rust issues on github and nothing appears to be there but I wanted to check my understanding before raising an issue.

```
type mismatch resolving `<Vec<f64> as IntoIterator>::Item == (dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)`
expected trait object `(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)`
           found type `f64` rustc (E0271)
```

Edit:
The ToString trait is what I actually tried first, and it gives the same error

```
type mismatch resolving `<Vec<f64> as IntoIterator>::Item == (dyn ToString + 'static)`
expected trait object `(dyn ToString + 'static)`
           found type `f64` rustc (E0271)
```

Edit:
Added relevant code. I also have an error where the compiler complains about x not being a reference, which I haven't figured out and is why I didn't initially have the code in this question.

```
use std::error::Error;

// Write to a file
pub fn write_to_file<T>(data_line: T) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = dyn ToString> + len_trait::Len,
{
    let file = std::fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .create(true)
        .append(true)
        .open("test_data/data.tsv")
        .unwrap();

    let mut wtr = csv::WriterBuilder::new()
        .delimiter(b'\t')
        .quote_style(csv::QuoteStyle::NonNumeric)
        .from_writer(file);

    let mut data_line_str: Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(data_line.len());

    // into_iter() is used instead of iter() because iter() doesn't have a trait
    // and into_iter() consumes the reference, not the original object
    data_line
        .into_iter()
        .for_each(|x| data_line_str.push(x.to_string()));

    wtr.write_record(&data_line_str)?;

    wtr.flush()?;
    Ok(())
}

// Use assertions to check for problems
#[test]
fn test_write() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
{
    let test: Vec<f64> = vec![1.423, 0.61324, 123.865];
    write_to_file(test)?;
    // Could use assert_eq! and open file and check matching
    let _remove_success = std::fs::remove_file("test_data/data.tsv");
    Ok(())
}
```

Edit:

I've tried changing the function definition, haven't changed to use collect yet because I'm trying to pick apart how this works, and I get this error... I thought I understood but now I'm confused again.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `len` found for type parameter `T` in the current scope
  --> src/io.rs:22:71
   |
4  | pub fn write_to_file<T, I>(data_line: T) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
   |                      - method `len` not found for this type parameter
...
22 |     let mut data_line_str: Vec<String> = Vec::with_capacity(data_line.len());
   |                                                                       ^^^ method not found in `T`
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the type parameter is bounded by the trait
help: the following traits define an item `len`, perhaps you need to restrict type parameter `T` with one of them:
   |
6  |     T: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I> + ExactSizeIterator,
   |                                   +++++++++++++++++++
6  |     T: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I> + FixedInitializer,
   |                                   ++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

Final edit:
I believe that I understand the issue. When I bound `IntoIterator::IntoIter` to `ExactSizeIterator`, that is specifying what the object that can be turned into an iterator (that is, implements IntoIterator) is turned into an `ExactSizeIterator` which at that point has a `len()`. So data_line may not have a `len()` method, but `data_line.into_iter()` would when I do as PitaJ suggests and use a type signature like

```
pub fn write_to_file<T, I>(data_line: T) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: IntoIterator<IntoIter = I>,
    I: ExactSizeIterator,
    <I as Iterator>::Item: ToString,
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please share `len_trait` as well, or modify your code so that it isn't included.

Comment: This is not my own. I tried using ExactSizeIterator, but Vec doesn't implement that despite having a len() method, which is why I'm including this: https://docs.rs/len-trait/latest/len_trait/

Comment: `ExactSizeIterator` is implemented for both [`vec::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html#impl-ExactSizeIterator-97) and for [`slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html#impl-ExactSizeIterator-44) which covers both `vec.into_iter()` and `vec.iter()`.

Comment: Which is why that's what I tried first, but it wouldn't work: ```
the trait bound Vec<f64>: ExactSizeIterator is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait ExactSizeIterator: ```

Comment: I do recommend using `collect()` instead of `for_each(|x| data_line_str.push`

Comment: Ok so am I wrong using the ```len_trait::Len``` instead of ```ExactSizeIterator``` then?

Comment: I'd probably do something like [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=90521a7f94cff00d6b3a9079eaa4c691) instead.

Comment: Ok, that explains how I'm supposed to specify it. IntoIterator has an associated IntoIter type and that is where ExactSizeIterator placed.

Comment: Note that with my solution, you don't need to explicitly handle `len()` and `with_capacity()` - `collect` handles that for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247528/discussion-between-liam-clink-and-pitaj).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
T: IntoIterator<Item = dyn ToString> + len_trait::Len,
```

What this says is "I expect `T` to be able to be converted into an iterator containing *some unknown type* of trait objects for `ToString`. That's actually a pretty complicated iterator type, and since `dyn ToString` is unsized, I'm not entirely confident you can *ever* have any valid instance of this type.

In most reasonable use cases for this function, we know the type of the iterator at compile time, so you're looking for generics, not trait objects. Consider

```
pub fn write_to_file<T, I>(data_line: T) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = I> + len_trait::Len,
    I: ToString
```

Comment: How is breaking into two parts generics instead of traits? Like all you did is replace ```ToString``` with ```I``` and then say ```I``` is ```ToString```, what makes this different?

Comment: That is, how does breaking them up help the sizing problem?

Comment: `Item = dyn ToString` is a lot like `Item = u32`. That is, it is saying "the type `Item` must be a `dyn ToString`". By splitting this into two generics, we can instead say "the type `Item` is some generic type `I`, and that generic type `I` must implement the trait `ToString`".

Comment: `dyn ToString` is a special object called a trait object. It is *not* equivalent to a generic argument. The former gets compiled to a runtime vtable; the latter is monomorphized out at compile-time. If you want to omit the type argument, the equivalent to what I wrote would be called `impl ToString`, but you can't use that syntax and the generic argument `<T>` in the same function, which is why I gave it a generic name.